# Why can't I run the statements in main() after my threads stop working?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

So I have a program with 4 threads, all of them running. 
3 of these threads are always running, even when the program finishes its work.
So I created some variables, to make them stop.

I changed the `while(true)` to `while(exit)` and the program works fine.

After the threads, I want to run some other statements, but only if the threads have stopped.

I tried using 4 variables, exit,exit1,exit2,exit3 and set them false. The thread will finish and make these variables true.

In main, after `Thread.start()`, If i want to print something, it doesn't print.

```
Thread1.start();
Thread2.start();
Thread3.start();
Thread4.start();

// System.out.println("Program Ended") --> If i do this, it prints before 
// the threads

if(exit && exit2 && exit3 && exit4) {
    System.out.println("Program Ended");
    // code here 
}
```

Is there a way to make sure I run some statements only after the threads have stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Thread` class has a method that does that for you [join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--) will block until the thread has finished executing. [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-join) tutorial how to use `Thread#join`

So your code should look like that:

```
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
thread3.start();
thread4.start();

thread1.join();
thread2.join();
thread3.join();
thread4.join();

if(exit && exit2 && exit3 && exit4) {
    System.out.println("Program Ended");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, you should consider `CyclicBarrier` or `CountDownLatch`.
These are less error prone, generally less verbose and fairly efficient compared to custom termination thread flags.

There are their specificities but are rather close. 
 `CountDownLatch` associates a counter  of "countDown" operations to reach to go on while `CyclicBarrier` associates a counter of distinct thread invoking `await()` on to apply a specific processing.

With  `CyclicBarrier` it could look like :

```
CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(4, () -> {
        System.out.println("Program Ended");
});
```

Here `4` is the number of Thread that has to wait for on the barrier and "Program Ended" will be displayed when 4 distinct threads "have reached" the barrier.

Thread could reach the barrier after their processing such as :

```
new Thread(() -> {
    while (!done()) {
        ....
    }
    barrier.await();  // replace the flag boolean
});
```

Note that the barrier is cyclic. It means that it may be reused after it was activated.  Contrary to `CountDownLatch`.

Answer (score 0):

Your if block is not guaranteed to run after all threads. You will have to explicitly make your main thread wait for those threads by calling `thread.join()` on each of them:

```
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
thread3.start();
thread4.start();

thread1.join();
thread2.join();
thread3.join();
thread4.join();

if (exit && exit2 && exit3 && exit4) {
    System.out.println("Program Ended");
}
```

This will ensure that the `if` block only runs after each of the threads has died.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ThreadGroup` to manage multiple threads might be more elegant & convenient when there are a lot threads.

**Sample code:**

```
ThreadGroup tg = new ThreadGroup("runner");

new Thread(tg, () -> {
    // ...
}, "t-1").start();

new Thread(tg, () -> {
    // ...
}, "t-2").start();

// create more  threads,

Thread[] tArr = new Thread[tg.activeCount()];
cg.enumerate(tArr); // get threads,

// wait all consumers to finish,
for (Thread t : tArr) {
    t.join();
}
```

**Tips:**

- When creating new thread, specify thread group in constructor.
- After starting all sub threads, get the threads from thread group, and join on each of them.

**BTW:**

- `ThreadGroup.activeCount()` will only return threads that are not terminated yet.